# flask variable is not showing up in my html

Tags: python, flask

```
    from flask import Flask,render_template
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route("/")
    def app0():
        headline = "Atlast You show up!"
        return render_template("app0.html", headline=headline) 
    if _name_=="_main_"
        app.run(debug=True)
```

my html code is-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My First Flask Substitution</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>{{headline}}</h2>
</body>
</html>
```

running the code says indentation error at my python return statement " unindent does not match any outer indentation level"
what should i do??please help

Comment: show full code of flask and error line as well

Answer (score 1):

Change your if statement to the following. See the difference?

```
    if __name__ == "__main__":
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is you may have given spaces for indent and tabs for indent as well. either use tabs for indent in whole code or use 4 spaces as indent.

and also in your code

change

```
if _name_=="_main_":
```

to

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
```